# Solving $12x \equiv 20 \pmod{38}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$12x \equiv 20 \pmod{38}$

$gcd(12,38)=2$ using Euclidean Algorithm.

There is a solution since $2|20$.

Use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm $2=12*-3 +1*38$

Then $20=2*10=12*-3*10+1*38*10$ so $x=-3*10=-30$ is a solution.

General solution: $x=-30+19t$ where t is an integer.

My question is: is the above correct or should $-30$ be changed to a positive number i.e. $8$

Comment: No but I just wanted to ask which one is better to state.

Comment: Also I followed the notes - why is -30 a solution from my working out?

Comment: Observe that $$12(-30 + 19t) \equiv -360 + 228t \equiv -380 + 20 + 228t \equiv 20 + 38(-10 + 6t) \equiv 20 \pmod{38}$$ so your solution is valid.  Also, $-30 \equiv 8 \pmod{38}$, so you can express your solution either way.

Answer (score 1):

A simplification is to notice that $12x\equiv20\pmod{38}$ if and only if $6x\equiv10\pmod{19}$. Now,
\begin{align}
6\cdot3=18&\equiv-1\pmod{19}\\
6\cdot16\equiv6\cdot(-3)&\equiv1\qquad\text{so that}\\
6^{-1}&\equiv16\quad\text{and thus we get}\\
x\equiv6^{-1}\cdot6x\equiv16\cdot10=160&\equiv8\pmod{19}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Assume $x(t) = -30 + 19t$ is a general solution, so that $12x(t) \equiv 20 \ (\text{mod }38)$ for all integers $t$.

Then $g(t) = x(t) + n\cdot 38$ is also a general solution for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ since

$$12g = 12x + 12\cdot n\cdot 38 \equiv 12x \ (\text{mod }38) \text{, and } 12x\equiv 20 \ (\text{mod } 38)$$

For all integers $t$.

Your solutions are equivalent!